Selenium Grid executed inside Docker doesn't download file automatically
I'm trying to deploy an application that uses Selenium to download PDF files from a web page. If I run my containers locally, the one with my Python application and the other with Selenium Grid, it works correctly and generates the expected files automatically inside the specified directory.
But when I run this same set of containers inside a remote server, for deployment purposes, it shows me a finder menu that asks me to confirm the download of the file, anyone knows about how to fix this problem?
Change the directory of the files, and I'm trying to download the file automatically.
My docker-compose.ymlfile is the following:
version: "3.9"

networks:
  publican-back-network:
    name: publican-back-network

volumes:
  publican-back-volume:
    name: publican-back-volume

services:
  publican-back-db:
    container_name: publican-back-db

    image: mysql:latest

    env_file:
      - ./environments/local-container.env
    
    volumes:
      - publican-back-volume:/var/lib/mysql

    ports:
      - 7221:3306

    networks:
      - publican-back-network

    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD", "mysqladmin" ,"ping", "-h", "localhost"]
      timeout: 20s
      retries: 10

  selenium-grid-service:
    container_name: selenium-grid-service

    image: selenium/standalone-chrome:latest

    shm_size: 2g
    
    volumes:
      - ./downloaded_files:/home/seluser/Downloads

    ports:
      - 7865:7900
      - 4441:4444
    
    networks:
      - publican-back-network
    
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD", "wget", "--spider", "http://localhost:4444"]
      interval: 10s
      timeout: 5s
      retries: 3

  publican-back-service:
    container_name: publican-back-service

    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
      target: runtime-stage

    image: publican-back-image:1.0

    volumes:
      - ./downloaded_files:/app/downloaded_files

    env_file:
      - ./environments/local-container.env

    networks:
      - publican-back-network

    depends_on:
      selenium-grid-service:
        condition: service_healthy
      
      publican-back-db:
        condition: service_healthy



enter image description here

You need to check the proper folder mapping in the volume section.
volumes:
      - "/home/user/Downloads:/home/docker-image/downloads"

